# How to measure execution time of asynchronous process in Datadog?

Tags: asynchronous, monitoring, metrics, execution-time, datadog

I have a microservice based project with `kafka`, which I used for event bus. I have a business process, which contains multiple microservices. Microservices asynchronous communicate with each other with help kafka. Each instance of business process has unique `process_id`.

Let's consider a example of some process:

1. User creates a process with `request_id == 556bb813-bf77-4f5f-8bb0-1a59d6ba16b4` in API gateway service.
2. API gateway service produce some event to `service1_in`. Of course, event contains `556bb813-bf77-4f5f-8bb0-1a59d6ba16b4`.
3. Microservice_1 consumes event from `service1_in` and produces event to `service2_in`.
4. Microservice_2 consumes event from `service2_in` and produces event to `service1_in`.
5. Microservice_1 consumes event from `service1_in` and produces event to `service1_out`.
6. API gateway service  consumes event from `service1_out` and eventually returns result to Client.

So, I need to measure execution time bwtween differ steps of this process. For example, I want to know, duration between steps `3` and `5`, or `2` and `6`.

So, I don't know, how to measure it. I have only one workaround solution. I can have share memory (e.g., redis), where I can store points of time for each stem of process. In the end of process, I can calculate all metrics and push it datadog.

Comment: This looks like a great fit for Datadog [distributed tracing](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/), essentially your microservices have Datadog APM instrumentation library and the following headers: x-request-id, x-datadog-trace-id, x-datadog-parent-id being passed from one service to the other. That will make them linked together. One good example of that is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw6rOh_PPZE